# How do I launch a URL in a specific user instance of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to intercept a web request and launch that URL in another instance of Chrome. We have a Google Apps for Business account. And I regularly receive emails with Google Drive links. But they open in the last browser that had focus, which can be my personal user window. I'm looking to have Chrome get that web request, then either automatically open the link in the right window, or prompt for a choice. Is that possible?

Comment: Define "another instance of Chrome" better, please.

Comment: He means another chrome user. Highly doubt its possible to do so.